# Cannot redeclare GuzzleHttp\Promise\queue()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Today I ran into a problem which I could not solve. I am developing at the moment some different packages. Lets say package 1 and package 2. Both of the packages are using `guzzlehttp/client`.

In both service providers I register `GuzzleHttp/Client` with

```
$this->app->singleton('GuzzleHttp\Client', function()
{
    return new Client;
});
```

And in both packages I bind the custom class. e.g.

```
// Package 1

$this->app->bind('Me\Foo', function($app)
{
    return new Foo($app['GuzzleHttp\Client'], $app['config']);
});

// Package 2

$this->app->bind('Me\Bar', function($app)
{
    return new Bar($app['GuzzleHttp\Client'], $app['config']);
});
```

Now when I add both package to the providers array in file 'config/app.php' I received the following error.

> Cannot redeclare GuzzleHttp\Promise\queue() (previously declared in
>   /Users/me/Sites/laravel-workbench/me/package-1/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions.php:26)
>   in
>   /Users/me/Sites/laravel-workbench/me/package-2/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions.php
>   on line 34

What am I doing wrong?

Here is a link to one of the package's service provider: [JustYoServiceProvider](https://github.com/Appsketch/justyo/blob/master/src/Providers/YoServiceProvider.php)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I found out what caused the conflict. Will answer my question if I am sure.

Comment: Any update? I've had the same issue.

Comment: @AaranMcGuire are you using franzliedke/studio to develop packages? I think this caused the problem. Because when I install them both in a new project with composer there is no conflict.

Comment: Yh, I am.. Did you fix it? because I I moved the packages to the main project and back and it somehow worked.. dont know how. - But I bet that's not a permanent fix.

Comment: No I didn't fixed it. I send an e-mail to the developer with a question if it is possible studio caused this conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time ago. Never had the time to answer my own question.

the problem was caused by the studio package because both packages were made with the studio command. After installing both packages via composer there were no problems.